# read, write, and as_bytes function

Tags: c++

In Programming and principles chapter 11, the author gives the following code to demonstrate binary i/o:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>


#include<sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
    template<class T>
    char* as_bytes(T& i) // treat a T as a sequence of bytes
{
    void* addr = &i; // get the address of the first byte
    // of memory used to store the object
    return static_cast<char*>(addr); // treat that memory as bytes
}
int main()
{
    // open an istream for binary input from a file:
    cout << "Please enter input file name\n";
    string iname;
    cin >> iname;
    ifstream ifs {iname,ios_base::binary}; // note: stream mode
    // binary tells the stream not to try anything clever with the bytes
    // open an ostream for binary output to a file:
    cout << "Please enter output file name\n";
    string oname;
    cin >> oname;
    ofstream ofs {oname,ios_base::binary}; // note: stream mode
    // binary tells the stream not to try anything clever with the bytes

    vector<int> v;

    // read from binary file:
    for(int x; ifs.read(as_bytes(x),sizeof(int)); ) // note: reading bytes
        v.push_back(x);
    // . . . do something with v . . .
    // write to binary file:
    for(int x : v)
        ofs.write(as_bytes(x),sizeof(int)); // note: writing bytes
    return 0;
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Why is he reading a address to a uninitialized variable?
2. Why does the program cut off some chars at the end of the file?
3. Why and how is he pushing an uninitialized variable to a vector?

Comment: `as_bytes` might as well be a cast directly to `char *`. Strict aliasing guarantees that all objects can be viewed as an array of bytes. No need for the stop-over at `void *`.

Comment: some of the tricky nuances of working with binary data in c++

Comment: Binary can be really nasty. The [varying length of `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), the [different byte orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), [memory alignment and padding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object)... And they are nothing compared to the surprises you get the first time you write a `std::string` to a file.

Comment: Why don't you use `reinterpret_cast` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1 and 3

In

```
for(int x; ifs.read(as_bytes(x),sizeof(int)); )
```

`x` is passed into the function uninitialized, but `x`'s undefined value is not going to be used.

The `read` function is going to use the space allocated to `x` as a container. It will read one `int`'s worth of data from `ifs` and store it in `x`, giving `x` a known value that can then be safely used. Because the body of the loop will not enter unless an `int` was read from the file

```
v.push_back(x);
```

is guaranteed to have a valid value for `x`. That's assuming the input file contains valid `int`s.

## Problem 2

`ifs` is being read in blocks of `int` size. If the size of the file is not evenly divisible by the size of an `int` the final `read` will fail. The body of the loop is only entered if the `read` is successful, so no data is added to the vector and no data will be read from the `vector` and written to the output file.